# Unsafe attempt to load URL http: from https Nginx rev Proxy socket.io

Tags: ssl, https, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

So I have an app running behind Nginx in its http form...

I've been testing the app and it seems https is working fine, Only issue I have found is when I try to click on a link from a popup window
[image: link from a popup window]
 the other popup window is blank    [image: second popup is empty]
 and under the devTools console I get the following error...

`Unsafe attempt to load URL http://dev84.mydomain.com/prweb/app/PegaRULES_/pbdorj4V2aBoI4ScEONLsEaxdEWiqDby*/SysWebInfo/MapWebInfo.xsl from frame with URL https://dev84.mydomain.com/prweb/app/PegaRULES_/pbdorj4V2aBoI4ScEONLsEaxdEWiqDby*/!STANDARD?pyActivity=%40baseclass.pzProcessURLInWindow&pyPreActivity=GetWebInfo&target=popup&portalThreadName=STANDARD&portalName=Developer&pzHarnessID=HID8FA7FD58600ED1BD74EB1DAA70BB4DA5. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

So I think I'm missing something in my nginx conf?  I've being playing around with previous confs that work on a similar version of the app that didn't have sockets so I'be seen that this version works pretty much all just with the socket configuration but I know I'm missing something

```
server {
        listen         80; 
        server_name    dev84.mydomain.com;
        return         301 https://dev84.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name dev84.mydomain.com;
        listen         443 ssl ;
        location / { 
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_redirect off;
###################################################old conf#########
                #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                #proxy_connect_timeout 90;
                #proxy_send_timeout 90;
                #proxy_read_timeout 90;
                #proxy_buffer_size 16k;
                #proxy_buffers 32 8k;
                #proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                #client_max_body_size 100M;
###################################################old conf#########
                proxy_pass http://dev;
        }   
}
```

Comment: "Unsafe attempt to load URL http" Modern browsers disallow or strongly warn HTTPS resources using/linking to HTTP ones. So it is not a problem of configuration (which is offtopic here as not related to programming) but a problem of you making sure that all resources (iframes, fonts, scripts, css, etc.) are under an https scheme.

Comment: PS: please do not obfuscate badly, and do not use `mydomain.com` because it exists and certainly isn't yours. You can use `example.com` or `example.net` to anonymize things, although it is most of the time a better idea to just give the real names to let everyone troubleshoot things more easily and hence help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging up more, This conf was the one that worked for me...

```
server {
        server_name dev84.mydomain.com;
        listen         443 ssl ;
        location / { 
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://dev;
        }   
}
```